# Como pegar o erro de login? react native

Tags: react-native

Como exibir uma mensagem amigavel para o usuario quando o login não deu certo, ja tentei de varias formas mas não consegui. So funciona se o email e senha estiver correto.

```
const response = await api.post('/login', { email: email, senha: senha });

const { auth = false, token, msg } = response.data;

 if (auth) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
       navigation.navigate('Tarefas', { token: token });
   } else {
      Alert.alert('Erro de Login', 'Não foi possivel fazer o login');
      setIsLoading(false)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

O que deve estar ocorrendo é que quando você informa o e-mail ou a senha errada, o retorno não tem as informações que você espera. Pelo seu código, você espera receber auth, token e msg da requisição de login. Se auth e msg retornam em qualquer resposta, o problema pode estar que token somente é gerado em caso de sucesso.

Uma forma de fazer aparecer a mensagem amigável seria utilizar um try/catch. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```js
try {
 const response = await api.post('/login', { email: email, senha: senha });
 const { auth } = response.data;
 if (auth) { 
  const { token, msg } = response.data;
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token); 
  navigation.navigate('Tarefas', { token: token }); 
 } else { 
  Alert.alert('Erro de Login', 'Não foi possivel fazer o login'); 
  setIsLoading(false) 
 }
} catch (err) {
 Alert.alert('Erro de Login', 'Não foi possivel fazer o login'); 
 console.log("Error:" + err.message);
 
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo